# Can't access parent elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

I am using X-editable plugin that sends an ajax request. X-editable is binded to `<a class="editable">` element. This is the structure that I use:

```
<tr class="appender">
  <td>
    <a class="editable" ... ></a>
  </td>
  <some more td's here>
  
  <td class="totalHours"></td> <!-- This is an empty cell by default -->
</tr>
```

After successful response of x-editable, I am performing another request to calculate the total hours per corresponding table row. My JS code is below:

```
$(".editable").editable({
  // some X-editable options here...

  success: function(response, newValue) {
  
    if(!response.success) return response.message; //msg will be shown in editable form

    let start = $(this).parents('table.table').attr('data-start'); // everything is fine with it
    let end = $(this).parents('table.table').attr('data-end'); // and with this one too
    let pk = $(this).attr('data-pk'); // and with this one as well


    $.ajax({ // This is where I call my AJAX for the second time
      // Some AJAX options here as well...

      success: function(response) {
        // And this where problem begins:
        $(this).parents('td').closest(".totalHours").html(response.total);
      },
      error: function(response) {
        return response;
      }
    });
  });
```

As you can see, what I'm trying to achieve is to put a total hours number, received in my response, to the `td.totalHours`, but nothing happens.

When I'm trying to debug things and put the following code: `console.log($(this).parents('td').closest(".totalHours"))`, it shows me the following picture:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? As you can see, I CAN access other elements, because `start, end, pk` variables have the correct value (otherwise the request would return 422 status, since I have the Laravel Validation).

**P.S.** By the way, firstly, I've had this AJAX request as a Promise in another function and did like this:

```
callSecondAjaxRequest(parameters).then( /* Trying to find these elements */).catch(/* Similar code */);
```

But it didn't work either.

### Update:

Well, solved the problem like this:

```
selector = $(this); // This is outside my second AJAX call;

// My second AJAX call's success callback:
selector.parents('tr.appender').find(".totalHours").html(response.total);
```

And it worked. So, the question is a bit different: why the `$(this).parents('td').closest(".totalHours")` couldn't find the required element, but `selector.parents('tr.appender').find(".totalHours")` did the trick? Shouln't it be the same?

Comment: put `$(this)` in some variable outside ajax call i.e : `var selector =  $(this)` then just use `selector .parents('td').closest(".totalHours").html(response.total);` this is because ajax is not able to find current reference element .

Comment: @Swati, well, I did this: `selector.parents('.appender').closest(".totalHours").html(response.total);`, where `var selector = #(this)` and the selector declaration is outside the second ajax call (in the first one). And the result is still the same

Comment: Hi can you try like this : `selector.parents('.appender').find(".totalHours").html(response.total);`

Comment: Jup, already did and it worked (see Update 1). But why does it work and `.closest()` won't?

Comment: Read [this](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) for more information .

Comment: Thanks, @Swati! This solved my problem!

Comment: Actually 'this' in the 2nd Ajax request context is changed so you need to keep the element reference from the previous context that you did and finally achieve your goal. Since in the .editable({}) context you can get the reference to binded element using 'this' but in the $.ajax context reference binded is changed now therefore you wouldn't be able to access that element with 'this'.